# Datefield to select years

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I'm using a Datefield to get user birthday..But its very difficult to select very past years like 1987..Here I have to move 12 month to pass a Year..Is any way to acheive it easily?

```
                <mx:DateField  width="17%" height="75%" selectedDate="{new Date()}" formatString="MM/DD/YYYY" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable yearNavigationEnabled property of DateField control

```
<mx:DateField yearNavigationEnabled="true"/>
```

Just mouse press down on year navigation up arrow or down arrow it will increase/decrease.

Comment: It is the Answer. :) Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting this field into three list selectors, and populate each with sequential numbers, 1-31 for days, 1-12 for months (or use name selector), and 1900-current year (generated) for year. I have not ever seen any sites use such a combined field to select date of birth, this is used only for dates 1-2 months from current date. I expect such a component was NOT designed to select distant dates.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. :) But above answer of Raja Jaganathan is the solution that i want..